# Is it possible to save qgs file as older version?

Tags: qgis, qgs

I just got installed the version 2.6 of QGIS (OSGeo4W) on Windows 7. I am exploring the new capabilities and the compatibility of our tools with this new version, however, i have to keep on working on the old gqs files, because we have to send them to other users who do not have the newest versions, so, I must to be able to save my qgs files as 2.2 Valmiera version, is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

There is no dedicated functionality to save to older versions.

Usually, it is possible to open newer project files in older QGIS versions as long as the project does not contain functionality which is only available in the new version.

The only real way to know if it works is to try it out. Make a copy of the project and ask someone at the receiving end to try open it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the QGIS 2.2 .qgs file `read-only` in the operating system.

With that, you can still edit the underlaying data, but you have to save the project file to another file name, preferably with-qgs26 added to the file name. The old project file is still accessible with QGIS 2.2.

There is no problem having QGS2.2 in parallel on the same computer with the current 2.6 from OSGEO4W (or standalone too). I still have all versions since QGIS 1.8 running.
Only drawback is that the current Openlayers plugin will not work with older versions, and you can't have two versions of that.

Double-clicking on a project file usually starts the QGIS version that was installed last. You can change that behaviour by double-clicking once on `apps\qgis\bin\qgis.reg` of the desired version.