# QGS format : backward compatibility between QGIS 3 and QGIS2

Tags: qgis, file-formats, qgs

Some of my users may want, before finally migrate to *QGIS3 LTR*, to read with *QGIS2* some *qgs* project files made under *QGIS3*. I would recommend them not to do that.

But, for the sake of clarity:

- How is backward compatible a qgs file from QGIS3 to QGIS2 ?
- In this [old post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130605/is-it-possible-to-save-qgs-file-as-older-version), there is a proposed answer by *Underdark*, for a QGIS 2.6/2.2 case. Would the answer be the same in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backwards compatibility between QGIS 3.4 and 2.18: As long as the projects are saved using `.qgs`, there are no major problems. But: Some styling issues are not transferred between the versions, e.g. labeling and layer transparency. This can be quite annoying.

Comment: That's not true at all. There's no effort made in the project to ensure older versions can safely open files created in newer versions. Some **may** work (with differences), others are just as likely to crash an open or after an hour's use in 2.18...